# Where can I find free weather icons?

Tags: image, icons, weather

Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139944/where-can-one-find-free-software-icons-images

I have a need for free weather-related icons. Specifically, I need icons that you might see in a ten-day forecast (clear day/night, rainy day/night, etc.)  Where might I find such images?

**Requirements: Like the author of the question linked above, I would prefer to not rip anyone's intellectual property off.**

Comment: Is stackoverflow now condoning questions that essentially ask "can someone do a proper google search for me"? Where can I find icons?! You've got to be kidding me! And to think this question remains open while others to do with IT infrastructure have been closed. Poor form.

Comment: I contend that this IS software development/programming related.  Part of developing software is a good UI, which in turn translates to images and design.

Comment: Totally disagree. You didn't ask for good designs, you asked for free icons relating to weather. Absolutely NOTHING to do with programming at all. Even if you had asked about good design, it's a UI design problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: So if you disagree, down vote the question (which I'm sure you did).  Read the FAQ.  It says: "As long as your question is ... of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere ... it is welcome here."  People answered, and upvoted, so its obviously of interest to others.

Comment: Very useful to me, I was looking for the same information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Weather.com has a free xml service for which they provide an SDK. The SDK includes icons in 3 sizes (31x31, 61x61, and 93x93) for about 48 weather conditions. I cannot find anything in their agreement that forbids using the icons for anything but their service. (Nor does it specifically grant free redistribution)

They are quite nice so it might be worth looking into:

http://www.weather.com/services/xmloap.html

Comment: Heh. Their site is broken and none of the links work. My guess is that nobody in their organization has looked at this page in a while.

Answer (score 7):

http://flagrantdisregard.com/fd-weather-icons/

This is licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/) licence so can be used in commercial works (with attribution)

http://jyrik.deviantart.com/art/Weather-Icons-Shiny-5215175

This is licensed under the [Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/) licence and can't be used commercially.

Answer (score 4):

These aren't great but they are on the NOAA site and they have many to choose from. See http://www.nws.noaa.gov/weather/images/fcicons/

Comment: The NOAA icons are the only ones that I know of which are really and truly free for all uses. -- See their terms of service. Reason: the icons are paid for by the US taxpayer.

Answer (score 2):

Well a quick Google for ["weather icons"](http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&rlz=1B3GGGL_enUS276US276&q=weather+icons&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&resnum=1&ct=title) produced good results.  Or places like [deviantART](http://jyrik.deviantart.com/art/Weather-Icons-Shiny-5215175)  ([2nd link](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/icons/#order=9&q=weather)) are a good bet.

Answer (score 2):

The [Buuf Icon set](http://www.iconarchive.com/category/application/buuf-icons-by-mattahan.html) contains a subdirectory Things/Weda with 15 weather icons in it. It is CC Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0. No good for commercial apps, but okay if you are looking for something for a free app which I assume you are since you aren't willing to pay ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can find some really great icons here

http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project

it's an openSource icon theme

Answer (score 1):

You might The Open Clip Art website

> This project aims to create an archive of user contributed clip art that can be freely used. All graphics submitted to the project should be placed into the Public Domain according to the statement by the Creative Commons.

http://openclipart.org/media/tags/weather

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fordesigner.com/maps//3800-0.htm there is a free weather icons..